# Building string for Javascript - replaced with code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build a `string` that gets passed to a graph and rendered. But the `string` gets encoded to have html codes, instead of the inverted comma.

I build like this:

```
foreach (var i in result)
{
   items += string.Format("[\'{0}\', {1}],", i.Date.ToShortDateString(), i.Balance);
}
```

But on the page, the output is this:

```
[&#39;24/12/2013&#39;, -20.82],[&#39;25/12/2013&#39;, -20.82],[&#39;26/12/2013&#39;, -47.82],...
```

The script accepting the script looks like this:

```
 $.jqplot('chartdiv', [[@Model.data]],
```

How do I keep the formatting I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using Html.Raw?

```
Html.Raw(yourValue);
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$.jqplot('chartdiv', [[@Html.Raw(Model.data)]],
```